# Concatenate cmdlets Powershell or Azure CLI

Tags: azure

I am searching for command in powershell or Azure cli which shows me the total size of use a storage account, how many disks attached in virtual machine and version of SQL installed in VM.

It is possible to concatenate with Get-AzureRmStorageAccount cmdlets | Get-AzureRmVM to show results?

I will appreciate any reply.

Leonardo Almeida

Comment: Do you have to do this in one line? Seems a bit of an odd approach. What is it you are trying to achieve out of the end of this?

Comment: get-help will show you if the cmdlet will accept input via pipeline and what objects they produce and accept as input.

Answer (score 0):

As you can concatenate just about anything, I am sure you could if you really wanted to but it would be completely un-readable.

You will need to write a script to perform the actions you need.

To Get you started; I have provided links to some scripts / some code snippets:

*To get the billable size of a storage account*:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/scripts/storage-blobs-container-calculate-billing-size-powershell

*To get the number of data disks attached to a vm*:
`$datadisks = (Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName rg-name -Name vmName).DataDisks.count`

*Sql Version on a Machine*:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587077/how-do-i-check-for-the-sql-server-version-using-powershell

Comment: Hello Lachie,
Eatiu looking for a more automated script where you do not need to enter the names of the resource group and storage account to know the total size in GB or TB and whether the storage is in Standard or Premium.

Thanks for answering

Comment: No worries again that can be done but you will need to start writing it yourself, this is not a forum for people to write scripts for you.